# How to add subplot in python use matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas

I have a canvas to draw my figure in python and matplotlib
i want to add plot to that canvas dynamically
in fact i want to area of convas share bitwen all child plot
for example  if canvas have only one plot, all area of canvas alocated to this  and if add another plot to that canvas all area of canvas shared bitwen this tow plot and ...
**Note: I do not know in advance how many plot(charts) I am going to add to canvas**
thank you

Comment: Welcome Alisa, Your problem sounds complicated. You can increase Your chance of getting an answer if You provide source code and specify Your problem further.

Comment: You can also read this page here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional guidance